# 2 same fb like buttons on same page - how to find out which was clicked?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have 2 fb buttons on page. One on top of article and second on bottom. (I would like to test which button people respond better to). Is there any way to find out which button was clicked? maybe using google analytics or any other tool? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use events and callback from Facebook SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.7 `edge.create` callback return DOM element which FB button was clicked. Then you can use it with analytics events.